# Configuring apache2 server to serve up an application

Tags: apache, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have set up a source archive and I need apache 2 to serve up the application. The following are the contents of the README file:

> so, you have your source archive available, and installed somewhere.
>   next set up a web server, and configure it to serve up the application
>   from wherever, using the file sample-apache2.conf as a basis.

And the following are the contents of the **

**sample-apache2.conf**

** file that is supplied alongside the README file:

```
#
# In this example, the site is served directly from a dedicated virtualhost
#

# static content, such as images, css, etc
#Alias /static /home/seanius/patch-tracker/static
# a custom error page
#ErrorDocument 500 /static/500.html
# all other requests go through a central handler
#WSGIScriptAlias / /home/seanius/patch-tracker/pagehandler.py
#<Location />
#  WSGIProcessGroup patch-tracker
#</Location>

#
# In this example, the site is served relatively from the location
# /patch-tracking.debian.net on the default virtualhost/server
#

# static content, such as images, css, etc
Alias /patch-tracking.debian.net/static /home/seanius/patch-tracker/static
# a custom error page
ErrorDocument 500 /patch-tracking.debian.net/static/500.html
# all other requests go through a central handler
WSGIScriptAlias /patch-tracking.debian.net /home/seanius/patch-tracker/pagehandler.py
<Location /patch-tracking.debian.net>
  WSGIProcessGroup patch-tracker
</Location>


# and finally: an optional (highly recommend) config to run as a dedicated user
WSGIDaemonProcess patch-tracker user=patch-tracker group=patch-tracker processes=2 threads=10 maximum-requests=1000 umask=0022 display-name=patch-tracker
```

I referred the following sites but was unable to figure out how to configure the server:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps

Can somebody please tell me how to configure the apache server? (I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS as OS)

**Edit (clarifying further what my doubt is):** I have a source archive and the web application is written in python. There are python files in the application that handle the web requests and responses and everything else. I want my apache server to somehow run the python files when somebody wants to connect to the server (in my case, it is localhost). This is what I am unable to figure out.

Comment: Can you post error message or what You cannot figure out ? If You run `apt-get install apache2` then web server must be running fine by default without additional configuration.

Comment: Hello @Guntis, I have a source archive and the web application is written in python. There are python files in the application that handle the web requests and responses and everything else. I want my apache server to _somehow_ run the python files when somebody wants to connect to the server (in my case, it is localhost). This is what I am unable to figure out

Comment: @Guntis: The server is running fine. I am just unable to figure how to use the provided sample-apache.conf to configure my apache.

Comment: I think, that You must modify some file from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` there must be file called default, make a copy and modify that. You also must enter correct `Alias` path and others paths. patch-tracker process is running?

Comment: (in previous comment last sentence about patch-tracker process must ignore :) ) Look here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ Try to setup hello world example first (with python). And then try to configure your application